# How to use QString::replace on a const& parameter?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

What is the best way to call [`QString::replace`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-7) in a non-destructive way ?

I have a function taking a `const QString&` as a parameter, then I can't directly call call `replace` because this function modify the object (same for `remove`).
I would like to chain calls on the parameter and to use that as an expression like :

```
return myString.replace(QRegExp("\\s+"), "_").remove("someSuffix");
```

Of course I could change the function definition to take the QString by value instead of reference, but I don't like this solution. One could later wonder why we are not passing by reference like the rest of the parameters.

I can also make a local copy but is there any more practical/clean way ?

Comment: Passing by value is the best solution here, next one is to create local copy. What else do you need?

Comment: Your `myString` string should be a copy of the function's parameter you pass.

Comment: The most evil way (if the inital value is non-const): `return const_cast<QString&>(someValue).replace(QRegExp("\\s+"), "_").remove("someSuffix");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a temporary and operate on it:

```
return QString(argument).replace(QRegExp("\\s+"), "_").remove("someSuffix");
```

However, I don't see anything bad in accepting the argument by value. You are copying the argument in one way or another, and acepting by value clearly indicates this to the user.

Comment: I've come to that solution too. I really love the Ruby approach with `replace` and `replace!`, it's so convenient.